# Prevent Javascript from replacing beginning of string with NaN?

Tags: javascript, regex, odata, dynamics-crm

I am work on some OData query calls to Microsoft CRM and need my query in a very specific format.I am passing parameters to a function which then adds the URL to my query. What I am passing my retrieve function is as follows:

```
 webAPI.REST.retrieveEntity(
        "EntityDefinition",
        id,
        + "/Attributes(LogicalName='" + logicalAttribute + "')"
        + "/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.PicklistAttributeMetadata"
        + "?$select=LogicalName&$expand=OptionSet"
        , null)
```

In debugging my parameter with the query options is:

```
"NaNmylogicalattribute')/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.PicklistAttributeMetadata?$select=LogicalName&$expand=OptionSet"
```

As you can see, my "/Attributes(LogicalName=" was replaced with "NaN". How do I prevent this from occurring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
id,
+ "/Attributes(LogicalName='" + logicalAttribute + "')"
```

Since you aren't starting with a `String`, the leading `+` is coercing your `String` into a `Number` (it isn't a `Number`, hence `NaN`). Just remove that first leading `+` and it will work:

```
id,
"/Attributes(LogicalName='" + logicalAttribute + "')"
```